# RelativeLayout for 3 textViews, last one with layout_alignParentRight doesn't work properly

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with 3 `TextView`s inside, I want to put 3rd `TextView` after 2nd `TextView`, but also align to the `alignParentRight`, I am using the xml below, but I got result that 3rd `TextView` overlapped on top of 2nd `TextView`.

I tried to figure it out by myself such as add

`android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text2"` for 3rd textView with

`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` but still not working.

Can any guru give me some pointers? 
Thanks a lot.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bm_bked"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        android:text="Title2 long text text text, test long text, test long text"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bm_bk"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="text3"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your definition of text3:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text2"
```

A general solution for all possible text lengths of text2 isn't possible in XML, because the layout needs to know the right edge of the end of the last line of text2 taking line wrapping into account, but only the right edge of the entire text2 TextView is available.

Comment: hmmm. it seems working almost with your suggestion. If text2 is longer than the remaining space, then text3 is after text2, and at right of screen which is good.  But if text2 is just about the size of remaining space of the line, text3 can still cover that small part of text2..

Comment: What is the correct behaviour in that case? Move text3 to the next row and leave text2 as it is, or wrap text2 to the next row at the left edge of text3, or do both?

Comment: Samgak, Thanks a lot, I re-thought about it: For corner case that text2 is just about the remaining size of the line but the text3 will overlap it: current android behavior is prefect to me. If I move the text3 the next line, it will show the empty new line with only text3 at the right edge. I would not have that behavior.